# Connecting to PeopleSoft Component Interface from Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, websphere, adapter, peoplesoft

We have an existing WebSphere message broker application that connects to a PeopleSoft component interface by way of an adapter. The application simply Polls with 'assured-once event delivery' to the component interface every so often and then performs some simple tasks.

I am looking to port this to an application away from WebSphere message broker to one built in Visual Studio but I cannot find anything as a direct replacement for the PeopleSoft adapter. I don't want to use Biztalk, does anyone know of an adapter that is available for Visual Studio directly or any other way of doing this? I am also trying to avoid changes to the Peoplesoft side of things and so don't want to delve in and expose anything further via web services.

Comment: Really, you're marking this down for putting websphere instead of WebSphere and 'webservice' instead of 'web service'!! Really unhelpful!! If you don't know the answer why don't you just ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just sending messages to integration broker, you can send the same messages in C# (xml most likely).

If you're talking about the Java templates for component interfaces, there is no C# equivalent.